# Pragma solidity not working

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix, error, browsers

[image]

Dear all, I am very new to Ethereum, noob-new. This might anger many but, i have to ask, why is pragma solidity not functioning correctly. I have seem countless examples where pragma solidity ^0.4.0; works, but why doesn't it work for me? I tried this out on remix.ethereum.org, the ethereum browser based compiler.

I receive this error, help please, anyone!

browser/Untitled.sol:1:1: ParserError: Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library definition.
`pragma solidity ^0.4.0;`

Here is the code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract MyfirstContract{
    string private name;
    uint private age;

    function setName(string newName){
        name=newName;
    }
    fucntion getName() returns (string){
        return;

    }

}
```

Comment: You should post your code as a code block so it can be copypasted and tried out. If it's a picture nobody can copy it. My current guess is that you have some strange symbol somewhere there which would become apparent if we could copypaste the code.

Comment: The code is working fine. Check your version of remix.`function` is misspelled in getName(). Correct that.

Comment: Heh, oops, noob mistake. compiler says its not loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs when compiler has not loaded yet. You should wait for some time

For statement like `pragma solidity ^0.4.11`, waiting for some time will make that error go away. In this statement, by using `^` we are saying to use any compiler above `0.4.11` so if `0.4.21` is loaded, then also it will work.

But sometimes this error can stay. This happens if you are using specific compiler version, as in the line below:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.3;
```

In that case, go to the settings section given on right handside, and select the compiler version which you are using.

Answer (score 2):

In case it isn't clear.

`pragma` "In computer programming, a directive or pragma (from "pragmatic") is a language construct that specifies how a compiler (or other translator) should process its input." - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directive_(programming)

It's just saying it was designed for a compiler of version `0.4.0` or better (`^`). The `solc` compiler is designed to raise an error if it, itself, is not compatible, and this can be a helpful safeguard - possibly preventing an incompatible or untested compiler from being used.

As @Ayushya pointed out, the compiler itself takes a few seconds to load and initialise. In the case of an incompatible compiler, Remix let's the developer choose from a lengthy list of available compilers, so you don't have to settle for the default.

[image]

The `pragma` may be telling you which version of the compiler you need to load to successfully work with a source file. This is potentially important when working with tested code because breaking changes may have been introduced after publication. Words are deprecated from time to time.

Main takeaway: Remix lets you load any compiler you want/need and there are quite a few to choose from. `pragma` is there to prevent head-scratchers. It suggests which version the developer worked with and presumably tested the code with.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all.  I copied and paste exactly what you have posted here in your code.
You misspelled "function" on line 9 .
After correcting that, it compiles just fine for me.   I´m using Remix in Firefox.  See if the browser you choose isn´t causing an issue, if you still get an error after correcting the misspelled word.  Otherwise, try putting the SPDX License version.   Other than that, I would say your issue is the misspelled word.  [![compiles fine][2]][2]

[image]